# Como puedo defiir un método en VotesController para verificar quien creo la pregunta?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, ruby-on-rails

Deseo controlar de que el usuario que este logueado no sea el mismo que hizo la pregunta para evitar de que el usuario logueado vote por sus propias respuestas y preguntas pero que permita ver la fecha.

votes_controller.rb

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_voteable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @voteable.votes.create(user: current_user)
    redirect_to question_path(question), notice: "A successfully voted..."
  end

  def destroy
    @voteable.votes.where(user: current_user).take.try(:destroy)
    redirect_to question_path(question), notice: "Successfully removed vote..."
  end

  private

    def question
      @voteable.try(:question) || @voteable
    end
end
```

vote.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: votes
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  voteable_id   :integer
#  voteable_type :string
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  user_id       :integer
#

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  def  self.voted_by?(user, voteable)
    voteable.votes.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  end

end
```

questions/show.hrml.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
            <h2 class="title-question"><%= @question.title %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="questions">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                <% vote = Vote.voted_by?(current_user,  @question) %>
                <% if vote %>
                      <%= link_to question_vote_path(@question, vote), remote: true, method: :delete, class: "question-upvote upvote-active" do %>
                          <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                          <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                      <% end %>
                <% else %>
                      <%= link_to question_votes_path(@question), remote: true, method: :post, class: "question-upvote" do %>
                          <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                          <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                      <% end %>
                <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                    <span> <%= markdown(@question.body) %> </span>
                    <span class="comments">
                      <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
                    </span>
                      <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: [@question]} %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h2>(<%= @question.answers.count %>) Answer(s)</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% @question.answers.each do |answer|  %>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <% vote = Vote.voted_by?(current_user, answer) %>
                    <% if vote %>
                          <%= link_to question_answer_vote_path(@question, answer), remote: true, method: :delete, class: "question-upvote upvote-active" do %>
                              <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                              <span class="upvote-count"><%= answer.votes.count %></span>
                          <% end %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= link_to question_answer_votes_path(@question, answer, vote), remote: true, method: :post, class: "question-upvote" do %>
                                <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                                <span class="upvote-count"><%= answer.votes.count %></span>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                        <span> <%= markdown(answer.body) %> </span>
                        <span class="comments">
                          <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: answer} %>
                        </span>
                          <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: {commentable: [answer.question, answer]} %>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <% end %> <!-- end do |answer|-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h3 class="head-answer">Your answer</h3>
                    <%= render partial: "answers/form", locals: {question: @question} %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% else %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="question-upvote">
                        <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                        <span class="upvote-count"><%= @question.votes.count %></span>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                    <span> <%= markdown(@question.body) %> </span>
                    <span class="comments">
                        <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: @question} %>
                    </span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1 ">
                    <div>
                        <h2>(<%= @question.answers.count %>) Answer(s)</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
          <% @question.answers.each do |answer|  %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                  <div class="question-upvote">
                     <span class="upvote-arrow"></span>
                     <span class="upvote-count"><%= answer.votes.count %></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 body-show-question">
                      <span> <%= markdown(answer.body) %> </span>
                      <span class="comments">
                        <%= render partial: "comments/comments", locals: {commentable: answer} %>
                      </span>
                </div>
            </div>
          <% end %> <!-- end do |answer|-->
    </div><!-- end  class questions-->
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Deduzco debería invocar el método una vez se pregunte por la variable vote en cada parte de la vista para la pregunta y la respuesta.

¿Cómo puedo extraer el usuario de la pregunta seleccionada y pasarle el usuario logueado a un método para que dependiendo si es `true` o `false` no tenga acceso al *link* que crea el `vote`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de negar el acceso al *link*, podrías optar por enviar un mensaje al usuario cuando intente votar en alguna de sus publicaciones (tal como lo hace SO); esto podrías lograrlo comparando `@voteable.user_id` contra `current_user.id` y permitir el voto cuando sean valores distintos, por ejemplo:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_voteable, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    if same_user?
      flash[:error] = "You can't vote on your own posts"
    else
      @voteable.votes.create(user: current_user)
      flash[:notice] = "A successfully voted..."
    end

    redirect_to question_path(question)
  end

  def destroy
    @voteable.votes.where(user: current_user).take.try(:destroy)
    redirect_to question_path(question), notice: "Successfully removed vote..."
  end

  private

    def question
      @voteable.try(:question) || @voteable
    end

    def same_user?
      @voteable.user_id == current_user.id
    end
end
```

Dado que `user_id` está disponible tanto en `Question` como en `Answer` puedes utilizar `@voteable.user_id` sin tener la necesidad de revisar que tipo de `voteable` es.

Comment: Opté por este método, me parece más prácitco ya que se válida desde el create y no hay que manejar más instrucciones condicionales, alguna desventaja en cuanto a la otra solución?

Comment: @GarcíaHenry No, ninguna, solo es diferente en experincia de usuario, depende tus preferencias; claro que esta solución es más simple.